# What is the difference between the multiple Swift type casting syntax forms

Tags: swift, syntax, casting

When needing to do some type conversion in Swift, I noticed the language has two separate syntax forms for this. I was able to write this:

```
arr as [Any]
```

but also this:

```
[Any](arr)
```

What is the difference between these? It seems that in general, for any value `v` and type `T`, I can write all of these:

```
Expression  Has type  Behavior
==========  ========  ==============================================
v as  T     T         Compile error if v cannot have type T
v as? T     T?        Evaluates to nil if v does not have type T
v as! T     T         Runtime error if v does not have type T
T(v)        T         ???
```

**Questions: What the name is for syntax form `T(v)`? What are its semantics?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `T(v)` is *not* a form of type-casting – it's *[initialisation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)*. Saying `T(v)` will create a new instance of `T` by calling `T`'s `init(_:)` that takes a `v` argument.

In the case of `[Any](arr)`, this is just syntactic sugar for `Array<Any>.init(arr)` – which is `Array`'s [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538750-init) initialiser that accepts a [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence) of elements of the same static type as the `Array`'s `Element` type (in this case, `Any`). It will simply create a new array containing the elements of this sequence.

Comment: Aha, this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @jameshfisher Happy to help :)